# Having specific website access on specific EC2 instance under ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I wanted to know if there is an option in Amazon Web Services, two have two EC2 instances running, and me, as a developer, being able to have a direct access to one of my choice when both servers serve under the same domain.

By access, I mean regular access to the website via a web browser (e.g. `www.domain.com/some-post/`)

I want my site to continue be up and live. I currently have a single EC2 server that servers under www.domain.com. If I add another server via Elastic Load Balancer,I don't have control over which server the load balancer sends me.

I have a Wordpress site which I want to upgrade its theme, plugins and the core files, so I want only me to have access to that server and test it out. I could open a server and test it on a public ip, I did it, and it doesn't work as expected, so I need to run it under the original address to make sure that if it runs OK like that, it will run OK live.

The only way that I thought about doing it is to create an image of the server, create an EC2 instance, use a different domain name, restrict access to the server to my IP address, change in the DB to the new domain name, than after everything works, change the domain back to original and make the Elastic IP point to the new server.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't achieve this behavior with an ELB. This would totally defeat the purpose of an ELB - who's purpose is to evenly distribute traffic amongst the instances associated with it.

By the sounds of it, you're looking for a testing stage that you can use to test out new updates etc without damaging the live site.

You could always set up a DNS name for your domain for your testing stage - eg."alpha.mysite.com".

It's quite common practice to use environment variables for use cases like this. You might have an environment variable set on machines that on prod could be eg: stage=prod and on your testing stage could be stage=test. Then in your code, you can get this environment variable an do something different depending on what stage the code is running on. For example, use the prod/development database.

It might be an idea to start using [Code Deploy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) for pushing your code. This way, you can have deployment hooks set up your environment on each instance - install dependencies, load the code, start the application etc. And then using the environment variables already on the instances being deployed to, your code will do the correct thing.

I suppose you could put the test stage on a different port on your prod machines and that way you could use the same domain, but this would be a really bad idea. I think to get a safe, fault tolerant and scalable solution, you're going to need an additional DNS name. And you most certainly shouldn't use the same ELB. If you want to test load balancing for your test application, you should use an additional ELB.

In fact some people even go the lengths of using different AWS accounts for managing test environments.

You might also be interested in [Code Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you run multiple instances behind a single ELB and want to be able to access one of the instances to test upgrades. I assume that, while performance and testing the upgrade, you don't want other users to access that instance.

I can think of a few ways to accomplish this. Here are two practical ones:
1. Remove the instance from the load balancer using the AWS console or CLI. No requests to the ELB will go to this instance.
Access the instance you want to upgrade directly on it's own address. For this, the security group on the instance must be configured to allow HTTP connections from the outsite. You could allow only access from your own IP and the load balancer, for example.
2. Create another ELB for test purposes. Make sure that the instance you're upgrading only responds to the test ELB, not to the production ELB. Two ways to accomplish this: either remove it from the production ELB manually, or make the ELB health check on the instance fail. (in the latter case, you would need different healthchecks for the test and production elb).

My advice: when costs are an issue, go for option one. When the additional costs of an extra ELB is not an issue, go for option 2,  manually remove the instance from the production ELB while upgrading, and re-attach it when done and tested.

Update (i realized i didn't answer your question completely): for this to work without changing the domain in your database, you would need to point the machine you're testing from to the right host.
Two options:
1. When going for the direct http connection to the instance, make sure that the instance has an external ip. Put the domain in your hosts file and point it to the ip.
2. When going for an extra test elb, either point the domain in your hosts file to one of the ELB ip's, or run a local dns server that has a record for the domain with a CNAME to the ELB hostname.

Comment: The problem is that I want to test it on the same domain. This is because of the cache plugin, the way the site is configured in the database, the .htaccess rules. There are so many things to change and I want to know for sure that if I upgrade and it works, it will work live for sure.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that and am editing my answer now, hold tight ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Although verifying the correct upgrade of a single production node is a valid use case, in this case you're probably better off creating a separate test environment on a different domain.
This way, you can test all changes/upgrades in isolation.
For best results, you would need to periodically transfer the database from production to the test environment. You could write a database scripts that automatically changes the domain in the database so you can (partially or fully) automate the production-to-test-database-restore process.

Comment: It seems that there is now way out of doing it this way, which what I thought in the first place, although I posted a question maybe someone will come up with a creative way of solving this.